# Event isn't firing when using javascript to postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript, telerik

I'm trying to use Telerik's RadSpell to spellcheck some text when the user submits it.

The way this is supposed to work is by stopping the postback, triggering the spellcheck through javascript, then in the spellcheckfinished event manually starting the real postback.  The problem is that in the last step the Clicked event isn't firing for the button and the server side event handler never gets called.

Here is the relevant .aspx code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var spellCheckFinished = false;
    var btnClicked;

    function doSpellCheckStuff(btnTrigger) 
    {          
        btnClicked = btnTrigger;
        var spell = GetRadSpell('<%= rsMessage.ClientID %>');
     //   spell.add_clientCheckFinished(checkFinished);
        spell.startSpellCheck();
        return false;
    }

    function checkFinished(sender, args)
    {   
        args.SuppressCompleteMessage = true;
        setTimeout('MySubmit();', 100);
    }

    function MySubmit()
    {
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
            new WebForm_PostBackOptions(btnClicked.id, '', true, '', '', false, true)
        );
    }
</script>

<tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return doSpellCheckStuff(this);" Text="Submit" 
                            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <telerik:RadSpell   ID="rsMessage" ControlToCheck="txtMessage" ButtonType="None" 
                                UseClassicDialogs="true" FragmentIgnoreOptions="All" 
                                OnClientCheckFinished="checkFinished" runat="server" />
        </tr>
```

Any idea why btnSubmit_Click isn't getting called and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to inject your postback script as :

```
string script = @"function MySubmit(){" +
                  this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(myButton, string.Empty);
                  "}";

if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("myPostBackScript"))
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(MyPage), "myPostBackScript", script, true);
}
```

Comment: That did it with one minor change, add true to the end of RegisterClientScriptBlock... otherwise it just injects the text into your page and isn't considered a script.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, I forgot to add bool to add script tags, updating it now.

Answer (score 2):

The last like of doSpellCheckStuff() is returning false always, which stops the OnClick event listener from running.

Comment: So then how do I stop the postback to wait for the spellcheck and restart it after?

Comment: try returning true instead of false and see what happens.

Comment: If I return true it will immediately postback, which will prevent the spellchecker from running.  That's why I added return false in the first place...

Comment: sorry about that. I'm glad ScarletGarden could help you, though.